# Scroll-past-end on codeblocks

Tags: plugins, scrolling, code-blocks

Sublime text has a nice feature in that it lets you scroll past the end to position the text you're editing at the top of the window if you're editing the end of the document.

**This does not exist in code::blocks, but is there any plugin that allows it?**